# Bootstrap container to take full screen on Medium device and small device but half on large device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am using the bootstrap container to meet my requirements. The container fit perfectly on the large screen as I want. But my requirement is the fill the container on the medium screen and small screen

The container is full width on the small screen, but however for medium screen the width is same as large screen.

My variables for screens

```
$xsBreakpoint: 0px;
$smBreakpoint: 576px;
$mdBreakpoint: 768px;
$lgBreakpoint: 1024px;
$xlBreakpoint: 1200px;
```

Container css to take full height

```
.container {
      padding: 0px 0 !important;
    }
```

Html component using container

```
<div class="container">
  <app-help-support-component></app-help-support-component>
</div>
```

Screenshot on a large screen which is perfect as I required

[image]

On the small screen as shown in the below the space should be removed and take the whole screen

[image]

I want to remove the space and the container should take whole width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add media query for make change in container width for medium devices (Device Width <= 1024px) as you required.

for make change in container width in medium devices you need to add the following media query code to you css:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px){
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: hey dude, did you try this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Add this css for your container class:

```
@media (max-width: 1199px){
.container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    }
}
```